# iOS background compass

Tags: ios, core-motion

I'm just wondering if it is possible to use "Core Motion" on iOS to track the users movement direction?
Is it possible to use the framework in my app, while it's not in use, to log where approximately the user moved (from some starting point) and calculate where he went relatively to the starting point...

For example: knowing that the user made 20 steps north and then 10 more west could give me an approximation that the user is somewhere around 22 steps (approximated to meters ofc) north-northwest...

Does anyone have any experience with Core Motion? Is something like this even possible without the app being opened or compass being calibrated?

Comment: it is possibile as you can fetch historic data but I'm not sure this is the right strategy. what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Finding the best possible location approximation of the user in areas where there's no gps/3g coverage....
My idea was that the user could save his location and from then on the app would track his every movement and tell him where he is relatively to the saved location...

Comment: this API should work also in background mode https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMSensorRecorder_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMSensorRecorder

Comment: I don't know about core Motion but, i think you can do this using didUpdateLocation and didUpdateHeading with CoreLocation Framework.

Comment: I understand what most of these sensors do, but is it possible to get "compass" direction with the magnetometer?